# TFS 2013 does not publish .coverage file on server

Tags: code-coverage, tfsbuild

I'm developing a quality workflow with TFS 2013 and SonarQube 4.5.1. Everything works fine except one thing: I can't integrate code coverage data from TFS to SonarQube. The problem is that SonarQube needs `.trx` or `.cover` files to work. 
However, my TFS Build doesn't publish those files. What I've done: I created a CodeCoverage.runsettings file that I mapped on my build with "User defined" type. (With CodeCoverageEnabled it doesn't work either.) In the file CodeCoverage.runsettings, I wrote the following XML tag:

```
<RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
</RunConfiguration>
```

in the hope that it would write all the results files in the same directory. The build does indeed create the results directories, but none of them contain `.coverage` files. However, at the end of the build, in the results page, I can download a `.coverage` file. Do you know how I can force the writing of this `.coverage` file on the server? When I run analysis on my local config, the file is created in the test results directory.